# How to vary ASP.NET Core response cache by query string only if response caching is enabled?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a class library with a controller, and I add `public` cache headers to responses.

This works fine if response caching isn't enabled for the consuming web app.

However, if the consuming web app has *response caching* enabled, it will cache responses from my controller **without varying by query string parameters**. In other words, regardless of parameters, the client will get the same response from the server.

I could solve this by adding an attribute to my controller like: `[ResponseCache(Duration = int.MaxValue, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any, VaryByQueryKeys = new [] { "*" })]`

However, that *only* works if the consuming app has response caching enabled. If not, an exception is thrown saying:

> InvalidOperationException: 'VaryByQueryKeys' requires the response
> cache middleware.

I can't add response caching through the class library (I don't want to force it upon the consuming web app), so how do I achieve `VaryByQueryKeys` for my controller *only if* the consuming app has response caching enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something like the following in an action method, and it seems to work:

```
// This will be null if response caching isn't enabled
var cachingFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IResponseCachingFeature>();
    
if (cachingFeature != null)
   cachingFeature.VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "*" };
}
    
Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
   new CacheControlHeaderValue()
   {
      Public = true,
      MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxAge)
};
```